# asterisk 1.6 not making outgoing calls

Tags: asterisk

I just installed an asterisk 1.6 on a ubuntu 12 on a vmware box. Asterisk seems to be working, but when I try to make a call using my voip provider, it says Maximum retries exceeded on for seqno 102 (Non-critical Request).

My sip.conf is as follows:

```
[vono]
type=peer
username=my_username
secret=my_passwd
domain=provider_domain.name
fromuser=my_user
fromdomain=vono.net.br
host=vono.net.br
insecure=invite,port; (no asterisk > 1.4 utilize "invite,port")
qualify=no
port=5060
nat=no
disallow=all
allow=ulaw
dtmfmode=rfc2833
context=recebe_vono
reinvite=no
canreinvite=no
```

I already tried with nat=yes and placing externip=my_public_ip on the file but it didn't work. 
Thanks for any help

Comment: The router had a sip algorithm that was interfering with everything. I turn it off and it worked

Answer (score 1):

You have allow in you vmware firewall port 5060 udp and forward it to you asterisk internal ip.

https://superuser.com/questions/136948/how-map-forward-port-under-ubuntu-for-other-machine-localhost-555-192-168